# How long would it take for a flashlight in space to reach an speed of 1000 metres per second?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, space

I started from the question of a solar sail https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_sail then imagined a flashlight sitting in space with no forces acting upon it, if it was then switched on, the photons leaving the flashlight would create a force of radiation pressure, so I wanted to know how far it would travel and what speed it would get to before it ran out of battery.

I started with working out the energy of a photon from $F_e = \frac{hc}{\lambda}$ and then assumed the flashlight had a mass of 500 grams, and seeing what would be required for it to get to an acceleration of $1000\space m \space s^{-1}$ so by F = MA i got that it would be 500 N of force. I then went to calculate how long it would take to generate 500 N of force, but when I started taking into account the circular shape of the part of the flashlight which emits the photons and how many photons would be generated by the average flashlight I began hitting a wall. Not to mention factoring in the battery dying at some point. I am still relatively new to physics so there is a good chance ive went about calculating this in the wrong way.

Any advice?

Comment: It's better to use momentum. Calculate the required momentum of a flashlight traveling at 1000 m/s.  A photon momentum is $E/c$.  That tells you how many photons are needed to be expelled to achieve this. Then you have to look up the radiant flux properties of a flashlight to see how many photons per second it emits

Comment: We generally close calculation-based questions, due to our [homework policy](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714). However, there are some interesting concepts associated with your question. I suggest you edit the question to focus on those concepts, rather than on the calculation details.

Comment: @Crogmcrob You mean speed instead ? Because you gave speed units $m/s$, not acceleration ($m/s^2$). I think photon sails will generate constant acceleration, depending on photon stream, it's wavelength, but rather minuscule due to low cross section of flashlight and low intensity of light. Solar sails on the other hand,- are more effective due to intensive sun radiation and possibility to construct high area sails, but alas Solar sails pushing force decreases with distance from the Sun, because of decreasing Sun particle wind intensity. So it's useless  when you get out into interstellar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have an object of mass $m$ subjected to force $F$ it will accelerate as $a=F/m$. That means that after time $t$ it will move with velocity $at$, and hence the time until it reaches some velocity of interest $v$ will be $t = v/a =vm/F$.

So for $m=0.5$ kg and a really bright 1000 lumen flashlight (about $P\approx 10$ Watt with LEDs; lets assume this is 100% efficient) that has $F=P/c=0.0000033$ Newton. So $t = 1000 \cdot 0.5/0.0000033 = 149,896,229$ seconds. About 4.7 years. Which honestly surprised me by being so short. Still, the battery will run out much earlier.

Comment: Conversely, one could start with an assembly that massed 500g, make a guess what fraction of its mass would be battery, compute the energy stored in the battery, and work out the change in velocity.  You'd have to choose the battery technology, of course (LiPo if you're going to launch today).

Comment: Will battery run out or not - depends on battery technology. For example, [radioisotope thermoelectric generator](https://voyager.jpl.nasa.gov/news/details.php?article_id=117) battery in Voyager 2 has operated for 45 years. Of course flashlight is not comparable to Voyager spaceprobe, but the point is that battery service time strongly depends on it's technology. So while typical AA battery will not last 5 years, but others could.

Answer (score 1):

m/s is a velocity unit, not an acceleration unit.

You can speak of what circumstances it can reach 1000 m/s, or you can talk about acceleration of $1000\,\text{m/s}^2$. In practice, the acceleration is basically maximum near the start, when velocity is minimal. And it is typically incredibly tiny, something like $10^{-6}\,\text{m/s}^2$ is already rather big.

Solar sails work by collecting light for incredibly long times, so that the accumulated momentum is big enough to matter.